# My UITabBar doesn't show up

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbar

Okay guys, maybe you can help me out with this one. I'm about ready to pull my hair out.

Recently I decided to upgrade my app and make it look better, and with that I wanted to move it into full support for iPad platforms as well. For a while everything worked great. Just press copy MainWindow.xib for iPad, add the views that I used on the iPhone configurations, and everything should be great, but that didn't work too well. Take a look:

Here is the **iPhone** screenshot:

[image: iPhone version]

Here is the **iPad** screenshot:

[image: iPad Version]

Where's the tab bar? I don't understand! I added the initial view when I was first putting it together, but when I linked all of the IBOutlets to the proper pieces, the tab bar no longer shows up.

Screenshot of IB:

[image: Interface Builder]

Tab Bar properties:

- Tint: A bluish color
- Image Tint: A goldish color
- Mode: Scale to fill
- Tag: 0
- User Interaction Enabled: (Checked)
- Multiple Touch: (Unchecked)
- Alpha: 1
- Opaque: (Checked)
- Hidden (Unchecked)
- Clears Graphic Context: (Checked)
- Clip Subviews: (Unchecked)
- Autoresize Subviews: (Checked)
- Stretching: (x,y,w,h):(0,0,1,1)

The viewController.h file is a delegate for UITabBar, UITextField, and UITextView

ViewDidLoad (bar is the IBOutlet for the tab bar):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self playMovieIntro];

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.faithlifefellowship.us/Audio/Sermons/NewSermonBanner.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    if(!image == NULL)
    {
        NewSermonBanner.image = image;
    }

    series = [[Series alloc] init];

    SeriesName = @"";

    NSRange range = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];

    int i = 0;

    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        i = 1;

    bar.selectedItem = hometab;

    //set delegates
    [bar setDelegate:self];
    [personalName setDelegate:self];
    [personalEmail setDelegate:self];
    [content setDelegate:self];
    [prContent setDelegate:self];
    [prName setDelegate:self];
    [prEmail setDelegate:self];
}
```

I'm stumped. If you have any ideas or need any more information, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give you a few things I'm getting in order to fix this. It will be tons easier if you could upload the source code for me/us to download and be able to pinpoint the problem.

Sometimes (I can't remember exactly when) I've had my navigation bar not show up because it was missing a connection.

Make sure you are not hiding the tab bar anywhere in code, though it doesn't seem to be the case since it shows up on iPhone.

Otherwise I'm gonna take a guess and say it's something in the NIB. Here are some things you can try:

- Check all your connections to outlets
- Make sure your objects in the NIB are of the correct class
- Verify that the tab bar's "hidden" property is not check in Interface Builder
- Compare and verify all the structure of the NIB file between iPhone and iPad

These are just some ideas :) again if you can post the code it would be fantastic.

Let us know how it goes,
Felipe

Comment: I did list all of the properties in my question, and Hidden is not checked. The only way I am able to get the bar to show up is to add it to the viewController that you see in the screenshot (as opposed to modifying the hidden property of different views to make the tab bar outside of the view controller. Thanks for your help; in the meantime I found a loophole that allowed me to get around the problem. +1

Comment: You're welcome :)

I'm happy to hear you were able to find a workaround to your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a app that support both iPhone and iPad. Make sure 'is initial view controller' is checked for the UITabBarController when you examine the view controller using the object inspector. When you do this, xcode will display a 'inbound' arrow on the left side of the view controller if you're using storyboards.